# Monotone Likelihood Ratio Property and Conditional Expectation

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I'm trying to figure out sufficient (and ideally minimal) conditions on two distributions f,g on [0,1] such that $E_f[x | x \geq c]$ $\geq$ $E_g[x | x \geq c]$, $\forall c \in [0,1]$. I am assuming, of course, that $E_f[x]$ $>$ $E_g[x]$, and I had been assuming First Order Stochastic Dominance. I realized yesterday that my proof that these conditions were sufficient had a very dumb flaw. I believe now that assuming $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ increasing (Monotone Likelihood Ratio Property) might be the correct assumption. It seems natural that if $f$ has a higher expectation than $g$ and increases faster than $g$ then it should have a higher expectation in a left truncated region. I've been having some difficulty proving/disproving this, however.

I am hoping that someone can point me in the right direction. I'll continue working on it as well as googling stuff, but my hope is that this is a known property of the MLRP or that there is a more simple way to approach it that I haven't seen.

Thanks!

Comment: But isn't this not true since the values aren't weighted? Wouldn't it be $(1-F(c)) E_f[x | x \geq c] = E_f[x | x \in R] - F(c) E_f[x | x < c]$ ?

Comment: Yes, weights were missing. Anyways with the weigths it seems the inequality doesnt lead to anywhere. But I can tell you the answer. You do not even need the MLRT condition. So actually MLRT implies first order dominance. With only first order dominance, one has two coupled random variables with the indicated statistical properties such that one of them is almost surely larger than the other. Then, given that $X>C$ the random variable which is larger produces always larger results such that all results are greater than $C$. So when one takes the limit, we get the desired result.